# Would it be a waste of time to apply to a lecturer position in my school at a different department after PhD?

Tags: phd, lecturer

I would like to apply to some lecturer positions after my graduation which is in August. My school happened to open a new position as lecturer in another department that I am not familiar with professors or anything. I would like to try my chances as it is a position that I'd be happy with and very interested in teaching. However, I read that universities tend not to hire their own PhD grads for tenure or non-tenure tracks like the one I would like to apply. I believe I am a very strong candidate for this position, yet I am curious if this would be a waste of time that the search committee will highly likely disregard me due to me being from the same school.

Comment: I think this depends on each university. For example, in my department I know a couple of lecturers that actually got their PhD here as well.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the department, the professors, etc., I'm kind of hard pressed to think that you would be a viable candidate.

Comment: @JonCuster The position is a big data analytics/optimization research/machine learning applications in business. I have done this in my dissertation and I do have data analyst/scientist experience in industry about 1 year. However, the department opening this position is not engineering. It's management department, and there is no single professor I do know since they do not work in my area or any of the mentioned topics above. I do hope this clarifies what I meant by "I am not familiar with the people in the department"

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good investment of time to get to know some of them before applying. (1) it shows interest, and (2) you can figure out if they mean what you think they mean.

Comment: @JonCuster  Thank you very much. That's a very good advice to figure out if they mean what i think they mean. I directly assumed their need is aligned with my experience and abilities. I plan to shoot the chair of search committee an email and ask more questions about the position. Hopefully this will clarify things in my mind and show them my interest.

Comment: I'd say people at the same school usually have an advantage overall, even where schools try to counter it. However many people will tend to view you as a student and not a colleague for a long time.